# How to show data using API in Django data table

Tags: python, django

I have created models.py inside profile_management app.

```
import requests
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from package_management.models import Package
from api_url_config import CREATE_CONNECTION_API_URL

class ClientProfile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    profile_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="default_profile")
    active_status = models.BooleanField(choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')], default=True)
    subscribed_package = models.ForeignKey(Package, related_name='client_profiles_subscribe', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                           default=1)
    plugin_platform = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    expire_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    company_email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    company_address = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    main_client = models.BooleanField(choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')], default=True)


    def profile_auto_increment_id(self):
        if self.pk:
            return f"#{self.pk}"
        else:
            return "(Not saved)"

    profile_auto_increment_id.short_description = 'ID'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.profile_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.send_data_to_api()


    def send_data_to_api(self):
        api_url = CREATE_CONNECTION_API_URL
        data = {
            "profile_name": self.profile_name,
            "active_status": self.active_status,
            "subscribed_package": self.subscribed_package.id,
            "plugin_platform": self.plugin_platform,
            "expire_date": str(self.expire_date),
            "company_email": self.company_email,
            "company_phone": self.company_phone,
            "website": self.website,
            "company_address": self.company_address,
            "main_client": self.main_client,
        }

        try:
            response = requests.post(api_url, json=data)
            response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error sending data to API: {e}")
```

Here I have send data to a API without saving on database. Previously I stored data on my local database, therefore I could show them on admin like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html
from profile_management.models import ClientProfile


@admin.register(ClientProfile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
    'profile_auto_increment_id', 'profile_name', 'profile_status', 'action_column')
    search_fields = ('profile_name',)
    list_filter = ('profile_status', )

    def profile_auto_increment_id(self, obj):
        if obj.pk:
            return f"#{obj.pk}"
        else:
            return "(Not saved)"

    profile_auto_increment_id.short_description = 'ID'

    def profile_auto_increment_id_link(self, obj):
        if obj.pk:
            return f"#{obj.pk}"
        else:
            return "(Not saved)"

    profile_auto_increment_id_link.admin_order_field = 'id'
    profile_auto_increment_id_link.short_description = 'ID'

    def action_column(self, obj):
        # This method is for the action column
        edit_url = reverse('admin:profile_management_clientprofile_change', args=[obj.pk])
        return format_html(
            '<a href="{}" class="button">Edit</a>', edit_url
        )

    action_column.short_description = 'Actions'
```

Now how can I get data from API and show on admin datatable? Example get API http://x.xxx.xxx.xx/api2/get_all_profile

Comment: I would keep in database or file to make less requests to API - because some APIs has limitation for number of requests.

Comment: @furas is there any way to do my task?

Answer (score 0):

I did like this and its worked.

view.py

```
def profile_view(request):
    api_url = GET_ALL_CONNECTION_API_URL
    try:
        curl_command = (
            f'curl -X GET {api_url} '
            f'-H "Content-Type: application/json"'
        )

        process = subprocess.Popen(curl_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output, _ = process.communicate()

        api_data = json.loads(output.decode('utf-8'))

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data from API: {e}")
        return None

    if 'data' in api_data:
        # Extract the data array from the response
        api_data_array = api_data['data']

        breadcrumbs = [{'url': '/', 'name': 'Home'},
                       {'url': '/profile_management/profile', 'name': 'Customer_Account_Management'}
                       ]

        # Pass the array to your Django template
        context = {
            'api_data_array': api_data_array,
            'available_apps': admin.site.get_app_list(request),
            'breadcrumbs': breadcrumbs
        }

    return render(request, 'admin/customer_account_list.html', context)
```

customer_account_list.html

```
{% for item in api_data_array %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{ item.project_env.profile_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.project_env.subscribed_package }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.project_env.company_email }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.project_env.main_client }}</td>
        <td>
           <p class="status-text">{{ item.project_env.active_status }}</p>
        </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```